# Angular-ui-tour is not recognized as a dependency in Angular / Require.js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am integrating Require.js to AngularJS based web application.

I am using library versions of the following

> - Browser: Chrome Version: 62.0
> - AngularJS: 1.6.6
> - Angular Bootstrap: 2.5.0
> - Angular UI Tour: 0.7.0

I have installed these libraries via Bower.
Here is my configuration.

```
define([
    'angular',
    'angular-sanitize',
    'angular-cookies',
    'angular-ui-tour'
    'framework'
], function(angular) {
   let yardiApp = angular.module('app', 
                       ['angular', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCookies', 'cafeangular']
});
```

Here, 'framework' is JS file that contains cafeangular module, which has bm.uitour as a dependency.

```
angular.module('cafeangular.service', ['bm.uiTour', function() {
     ....
}]);
```

But when the application starts, I got this message:

> Module 'bm.uitour' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If
>   registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second parameter.

I see angular-ui-tour is loaded correctly, but It isn't recognized as a dependency of cafeangular module.
Would you like to help me to fix this problem?

Comment: what is bm.uitour?

Comment: bm.uitour is module name of angular-ui-tour.

Comment: wrap 'framework' using define, and 'angular-ui-tour' is must be dependency for 'framework'

Comment: @HaegyunJung - Thanks. Yes. I've set angular-ui-tour as a dependency for 'framework'